# Is systemd service unit option Type=oneshot appropriate for scripts that take a while?

Tags: systemd

I would like to know which `Type` is the more appropriate for a service that run a script that takes a while and then complete. This unit is triggered by a `systemd.path` unit.

Naturally I would say oneshot, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The script can run for as long as you like.  This is because the usual timeout for service startup (90 seconds) is not enabled for `Type=oneshot`.  However if you want to enforce a timeout for a `Type=oneshot` service, you can simply set one manually.

> TimeoutStartSec=
>
> Configures the time to wait for start-up. If a daemon service does not signal start-up completion within the configured time, the
>              service will be considered failed and will be shut down again. Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min
>              20s". Pass "infinity" to disable the timeout logic. Defaults to DefaultTimeoutStartSec= from the manager configuration file, except
>              when Type=oneshot is used, in which case the timeout is disabled by default

-- [man systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

The other reason not to use `Type=simple`, is that your service status would be shown as "started" while it is running.  `Type=oneshot` will show a status of "starting" instead... perhaps this is not perfect, but I think it makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you. Last questions, since I have no idea of the timeout as the script duration varies, should I set it to infinity then?
Will systemd still detect the end of the service? Will it run the `ExecStop` after the end of the script run in `ExecStart`?

Comment: @Abitbol It's not clear from this question why you would need ExecStop at all, are you just curious?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the use of  `ExecStop`. My service is monitoring a *queue* folder, I run a script as a service whenever the folder is modified, it copies the file into a *processing* folder, when the processing is finished, the file is removed from *processing*. 
I wanted to use `ExecStop` for running a script that would clean *processing* in case the service is stopped or failed.

Comment: @Abitbol that makes good sense.  I think the correct answer is independent of `Type=oneshot`.  So you can open a new question for this, or look at the documentation for `ExecStop=` and see if it answers your question :-).  It is in the same man page linked above.